# Selector on every radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparative-review

I am constructing a selector on every radio button click. Since I am using the table repeatedly on every radio click, I cached it like:

```
var $t1 = $("#tableone");
```

but inside the radio check event, I need to retrieve the selector to construct a string.

**Approach 1:**

```
$radio.click(function () {
        var temp = $t1.selector + " ." + $(this).attr("mobnum");
```

**Note:** If I do not `$t1.selector`, it comes as [object][Object] which I do not want, so I have to use `$t1.selector`.

Since I am using `$t1.selector` to construct temp every time radio is clicked, is there still a benefit caching the table at the beginning?

**Approach 2:**

```
$radio.click(function () {
var temp = $("#tableone") + " ." + $(this).attr("mobnum");
```

Which one's better?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're doing.  FYI, `.selector` is deprecated, and may be removed from jQuery in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your approach 2 will do what you want. So I the first one would be better.

It looks to me though that you are building another selector. Probably to find the child element. So I would recommend something like this:

```
var $c = $t1.find("." + $(this).attr("mobnum")).
```

This returns the child element. This way you are already selecting only out of the children of `$t1`. Which would be more efficient, in theory.

Comment: So essentially now I can do operations on $c right. Like $($c).hide() or $($c).show() right?

Comment: That is correct, but you won't need to wrap it in a `$()`. `$c.show()` should be sufficient.